# How to create a new ejabberd virtual host with REST API?

Tags: xmpp, chat, ejabberd, multi-tenant

I am trying to setup a ejabberd server for my app. we have a saas model which needs to be separated based on subdomain. I am wondering if it is possible to create a virtual host in ejabberd with REST API as we cannot change config file for each signup.

any ideas or alternative solution would also work for me as I am not stuck with ejabberd as a solution.

Comment: **create a virtual host in ejabberd with REST API as we cannot change config file for each signup.** why do you want to make change in config with each signup?

Comment: here is an example. the virtualhost is company1.domain.com, this has its own users, company2.domain.com has its own users. we dont want them to be able to see each other